# Changing An iframe source from the listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the source of the iframe from a listbox. And here is my code.

```
<iframe id="iframeID" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
   <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="Pop Up HTML Preview" 
               OnClientClick="ShowPopUp();" />

 ShowPopUp = function() {
      var x = document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>');
      var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].Value;
      document.getElementById("iframeID").src = val;
```

But error says I have an undefined iframe.
What is wrong?
Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `runat=server` in your iframe try something like this `<iframe name="myIframe" id="ifraneID" width="100px" height="200px" runat =server></iframe>`

Comment: You should use `value` instead of `Value` in: `var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].Value;`

Comment: @fardjad Thank you. I forgot how case sensitive ASP.Net is.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the source using jquery:

`$("#content").attr('src', 'http://your new source here');`

so you can invoke this method when the selected item in the listbox is changed.

Comment: Putting jQuery everywhere is not a solution, it's a workaround

Comment: @PabloLemurr but why not using it in this code? the other option will be calling an asp method to do so, and then u have to make postback or use update panels.. 
jquery provides a much simpler solution i think..

Comment: It will not work because in most cases ASP will change the ID for its own as I explained in my post, besides if there is no jQuery library already included there is no point loading it just for doing this single task

Comment: I agree with than, still you can use ClientId or CSSClass :)

Comment: Besides, it's a great example of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492 ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `value`,  JavaScript is case sensitive

```
 var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

and change `OnClientClick` as below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="Pop Up HTML Preview" 
OnClientClick="ShowPopUp(); return false;" />
```

Button click event make full post back request to server. So again your Ifram will have default src value after postback. Here you have not given value as default src. So nothing will get after click on button. after you add `return false` button click will not postback after click.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't do anything from C#, make a normal button - ASP tends to add fancy prefixes to its controls' IDs (like `ContentPlaceHolder1_btnView`), and those can't be accessed that way by `.ID` from C# code. So you can either chceck these IDs (which are able to change if you move them somewhere else) by browser's source code inspector, or use

```
<input type="button" ID="btnView" Value="Pop Up HTML Preview" 
               OnClick="ShowPopUp();" />
```

(Modify your JS accordingly)